AWS EKS cluster level http-proxy cache
I am looking for a solution to enable my AWS EKS cluster nodes to have an http proxy based cache. Once my EKS cluster was created lets say that I have 100 nodes. Each of those nodes tries to download 10 jar files/docker images from an outside registry. The optimisation Im looking for comes from the fact that the overlap between these files is quiet big. Lets say that the overlap in files between two randomly selected nodes is averages to 5. In this scenario reaching out to the external registry is not cost nor speed efficient and I might be facing rate limits on the external registry as well. If I would have these files in a cache (well scaling both in bandwidth and cache size) that all my nodes can access and update I could in theory reduce my cost and increase the download speed.
